# Doubt on recursive definition of a term in a first order language, $\mathscr L$

Tags: first-order-logic

In his definition of a first order language $\mathscr L$ in *"A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Leary"*, the author says a **term** in $\mathscr L$ is a non-empty, $\underline {\text{finite}}$ string $t $ of symbols from $\mathscr L$ such that :

$1.) \;$ $t$ is a variable, or

$2.) \;$ $t$ is a constant symbol, or

$3.) \;$ $t$ is $f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n)$ where $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol of $\mathscr L$ and each $t_i$ is a **term** of $\mathscr L$.

Now this recursive definition is a little unsettling to me. Suppose, $ t$ is $f(c_1, c_2, l )$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are suitable constants of $\mathscr L$ and $l = f(c_1, c_2, l ) $. This conforms to the definition and hence $t$ is a term. But $t$ surely cannot be a finite string can it?

> Obviously the author's definition was foolproof (for this is a book on
>   logic). So I must have my thought process jumbled up. Can someone tell
>   me where? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Do you really mean $l = f(c_1, c_2, l )$? You can't define $l$ with respect to itself.

Comment: $l = f(c_{1}, c_{2}, l)$ is suspicious. Typo?

Comment: @GitGud Your comment is spot on, and addresses the problem.  However, I think that this *is* a pretty good question, especially for students that have some exposure to programming languages, because it's very easy to gloss over *freely-generated* structures, *initial* algebras, etc., and definitions of things like logical languages often omit that.  If the definition of the syntaxtic language just says, e.g., $\neg\phi$ is a formula whenever $\phi$ is, then there *is* a model of the language in which there is a sentence $s$ such that $s$ has the form $\neg s$. It's just not an *initial* model.

Comment: @GitGud It's sort of tangential to this question, but I first encountered this in Lisp programming, where you can programmatically construct circular lists.  It was confusing because the definition still seemed to be algebraic: every list is a either the empty list, or a pair of an element and another list (the tail).  Learning that algebraic data structures are the *initial algebras* for a specification was enlightening.  This seems like the same sort of situation.  I only point this out because it's not quite as simple as "you can't define something with respect to itself," because in many…

Comment: …situations in mathematics, we want to just that, or something very similar, and appeal to explicit constructions, or fix point semantics, or ….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git Gud & Brian have said everything I'm going to say, so read only if you still have some doubts.

The expression $f(c_1,c_2,l)$ is a term iff $f$ is a 3-ary function symbol (let's suppose it is) and $c_1$, $c_2$, *and* $l$ are terms of the language. Since $l$ is a defined symbol, for $t$ to be a term it is necessary that the definiens (namely $f(c_1,c_2,l)$) be a term. You can see the problem: the definition of $l$ is *circular* (and not *recursive*), so it fails to define $l$ as a term, so $t$, the 'finite string' fails to be a term.

Comment: **the problem: the definition of l is circular (and not recursive), so it fails to define l as a term, so t, the 'finite string' fails to be a term.** What's difficult here (and I've added comments on the main question) is that many texts don't quite specify that the language is an *initial algebra* for the specification. If the only restriction, e.g., on conjunctions is that "we have to be able to take the left side and the right side, and each must be a sentence", then there's nothing to stop us from considering a sentence $\phi$ such that $\phi$ is a conjunction and both the left and right…

Comment: sides of $\phi$ are also $\phi$.  That's obviously not a finite string, but it would be a sentence of *some models* of the language specification;  just not of an *initial algebra* model of the specification. Many authors handwave at this point, since the intended model  is usually intuitive.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks. That's a helpful way of thinking about it.